# SQL constraint for unique child rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a parent table Person. And 3 child tables PersonA, PersonB and PersonC.

```
Person - ID int primary key not null, name varchar(50) null
PersonA - ID int primary key not null references Person(ID), fname, lname, zip etc.
PersonB - ID int primary key not null references Person(ID), fname, lname, zip etc.
PersonC - ID int primary key not null references Person(ID), fname, lname, zip etc.
```

What I need to build is a constraint which will ensure that a person falls under only one of the three persons. For example if I have a row in Person with 234, JohnSmith with my current design I can have the same 234 in PersonA, PersonB and PersonC. My goal is to have the 234 in ONLY one of the three chilt tables.

Comment: I think you need to review your model. Four tables to handle person types? I advice you to study normalization.

Comment: I agree, it is sort of misleading. I am talking about providers, hospitals, caregivers etc. But they are all treated as single entities because they server our members. But anyway please do not concentrate on the semantics but tell me how do I accomplish this. One row in parent means one and only one corresponding row in one of its children.

Comment: I think that there is no way to do what you want through constraints the best way to you accomplish this would be using triggers.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Can't vote since I need more repuation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is by having three foreign key references in the `Person` table with a constraint:

```
PersonAID int references PersonA(ID),
PersonBID int references PersonB(ID),
PersonCID int references PersonC(ID),
check ((PersonAID is not null and PersonBID is null and PersonCID is null) or
       (PersonBID is not null and PersonCID is null and PersonAID is null) or
       (PersonCID is not null and PersonAID is null and PersonBID is null)
      )
```

Note:  if you want to allow all three to be `NULL`:

```
check ((PersonAID is not null and PersonBID is null and PersonCID is null) or
       (PersonBID is not null and PersonCID is null and PersonAID is null) or
       (PersonCID is not null and PersonAID is null and PersonBID is null) or
       (PersonAID is null and PersonBID is null and PersonCID is null)
      )
```

If you do this, then you may not need the reference from each of the subtables to the maintable.

Comment: That will make the main person table loose its design. Create the mapping table as suggested in my solution and this will keep data separately and normalised

Answer (score 0):

you can add constraint using insert trigger,  so when the row is getting inserted check that no other table has got the same row id. Alternatively create a mapping table that has got reference to the main person table with the main id  and another column Id referencing id of the child table.  Set primary key on main table id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a view of the union of the three child tables and then creating a unique index on this view? Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Create View Persons
as

Select ID From PersonA    
union    
Select ID From PersonB    
union    
Select ID From PersonC


--Create an index on the view.
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1 
    ON Persons (ID);
```

Comment: But this is just a view to see the data - it is not working like a constraint when inserting rows.